# Is hiding the H1 after first time visit bad for SEO?

Tags: seo

For search engines and new users I would like to display a H1 and some intro text for each page, but for regular users I don't want to display this content - is this likely to result in a penalty of some form?

Comment: How are you tracking the visit?  (cookies?)   Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You are describing a form of cloaking. I would avoid this.

Comment: What if the H1 and intro text were visible but when the user interacts with the page in some form it's hidden? I want the information there for SEO but to have the info there beyond a first visit to my site would be unnecessary

Comment: If you don't think you need an h1, then don't put one on.  Google can rank your pages just fine without an h1 tag.   Having an h1 tags was a SEO necessity 10 years ago, but today, it is unlikely to change things much.